# Вопрос по facebook а именно fb:ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

```
На сайте с тестами при нажатии поделится с друзьями отрабатывает такая функция:

function go_share()
{
   FB.ui(
      {
         method: 'feed',
         link: '<?php echo base_url().$this->language.'/test/'.$test['url']; ?>',
         picture: '<?php echo $img_url; ?>',
         name: '<?php echo $test['title_' . $this->language]; ?>',
      }
   );
}
```

Но в открывающемся окне с данными нет картинки! Вообще изредка картинка вставляется, при работе с дебагером фейсбука неколько раз пишет что не удалось загрузить картинку (1, иногда 2). Но потом подтягивает её и уже при нажатии снова на этом тесте с моими результатами картинка подтягивается! Помогите разобраться...

Comment: Добавлю что пробовал и через share сделать - результат тот же( Может быть такое что сервак на котором сайт лагает? Все пути перепроверил раз 10, все верно, сыллка на картинку верная.

Comment: Сервак не лагает... Перенесли сайт на другой - результат тот же. Ребята помогите